# Two events on same table

Tags: c#, charts, event-handling, google-visualization

I have a table, and a bar-chart visualizing the same content as in the table. When I select a specific row in the table I show another more detailed graph for that specific row and the bar-chart disappears (hidden). What I want, is to be able to also go the other way around: selecting a bar in the bar-chart should highlight the coherent row in the table, but without "clicking it" because then i triggers the "Selecthandler" on the table.

Below is a snippet of my code (the table):

```
 var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(dataRaw, false);
            var table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('errorTable'));
 var options = {

                cssClassNames: cssClassNames,
                allowHtml: true,
                title: "Error",

            };

            google.visualization.events.addListener(table, 'select', selectHandler);
            table.draw(data, options);
function selectHandler() {....ect.
```

Answer (score 0):

use chart method --> `setSelection(selection_array)`

from the [docs](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#vissetselection)...

> Optionally selects a data entry in the visualization—for example, a point in an area chart, or a bar in a bar chart. When this method is called, the visualization will visually indicate what the new selection is. The implementation of setSelection() will not fire a "select" event. Visualizations may ignore part of the selection. For example, a table chart can only show selected rows.

the table chart can only select entire rows, not columns or cells,
so we have to remove the column reference from the bar chart selection

when we use `getSelection` on a bar chart,
it will return an array of selection objects,
each will a key for `row` and `column`
e.g. --> `[{row: 0, column: 1}]`

when using `setSelection` on a table chart, we have to set the `column` value to `null`
e.g. --> `[{row: 0, column: null}]`

see following working snippet,
when the bar chart is selected, we use `getSelection`
then use the `map` method on the selection array to set the `column` values to `null`
then pass the new selection array to `setSelection` on the table

you will see when the bar chart is selected,
the same row in the table will be selected...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart', 'table']
}).then(function () {
  var dataRaw = [
    ['Category', 'Value'],
    ['A', 1],
    ['B', 2],
    ['C', 3],
    ['D', 4],
    ['E', 5],
    ['F', 6]
  ];

  var dataTable = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(dataRaw, false);
  var chartBar = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('successChart'));
  var chartTable = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('errorTable'));

  google.visualization.events.addListener(chartBar, 'select', selectHandler);

  chartBar.draw(dataTable, {
    selectionMode: 'multiple'
  });
  chartTable.draw(dataTable);

  function selectHandler() {
    var selectionBar = chartBar.getSelection();
    var selectionTable = selectionBar.map(function (selectedItem) {
      return {
        row: selectedItem.row,
        column: null
      };
    });
    chartTable.setSelection(selectionTable);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="successChart"></div>
<div id="errorTable"></div>
```